# AlignTab menu greyed out in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I installed the package manager, restarted Sublime, opened the file and tried to align a block of sql text using the AlignTab plugin. When I right clicked on the text and went to the Align submenu all the regex options were greyed out. Has anyone had this issue on Sublime Text 2?

Comment: not sure if this question is appropriate for SO. Maybe superuser would be more appropriate. (its a SO sistersite)

Comment: Did you restart after installing the plugin? I just installed it in ST2 on Ubuntu and it worked just fine for me - none of the options in the `Align By` menu were grayed out. If you open the console (Ctrl-`), can you find any error messages? It's also worth noting that, like many packages, ST2 support for this plugin is deprecated, and development will only continue on the ST3 branch. I strongly suggest you [upgrade](http://sublimetext.com/3), as the new version, is fast, has more features, and is very stable (I've been using it almost exclusively for over a year). There are also more plugins.